# What is the difference between &(str[i]) and (&str)[i]?

Tags: c

I have this kind of a situation where `str` is a classic string `const char *`, and I want to pass a substring. But when I went to look at the operator precedence table, I thought - maybe it doesn't even matter.

One is (to my understanding) the address of the char that is off set by i from str,

And the other is pointer arithmetic where you offset the pointer to str by i pointers.

What are the diferences, and which one should be preferable for speed?

Comment: `a[b]` is an alias for `*(a+b)`. So `&(str[i])` ⇔ `&(*(str+i))` ⇔ `str+i`, that is a pointer to the ith character (`str` being a pointer to the 0th one). `(&str)[i]` is `*((&str)+i)`. So if `str` (the variable containing the pointer) is stored at an address, `&str`, then `&str+i` is the address of another variable (or not, or an unused area, or another segment area, or some alignment padding, or...). And `*(&str[i])` is an attempt to access that area content (interpreted as a pointer to a char). Likely leading to a segfault, and surely leading to nothing wanted.

Comment: Think of the `&` operator as the *pointer-to* operator. Then for `&(str[i])` is easy to see that it's a *pointer-to `str[i]`*. In `(&str)[i]` you have a *pointer-to `str`* and then get an element from that pointer (if `str` is a `const char *`, then `&str` is a `const char **`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this kind of a situation where `str` is a classic string `const char *` ....

In C, a *string* is more like an *array* of characters with a *null character* at the end.  A *string* is not a pointer.  The situation is better described as a `const char *` pointer to a string.

> One (`&(str[i])`) is ... the address of the `char` that is off set by `i` from `str`,   ...

Yes, that is correct.

> And the other (`(&str)[i]`) is pointer arithmetic where you offset the pointer to `str` by `i` pointers.

Yes and the result is a pointer, but not certainly the same value as `&(str[i])`.

> What are the differences (?)

`&(str[i])` offsets along the string pointed to by `str`.

`(&str)[i]` offsets along the pointers near `str`, assuming they are valid `const char *` pointers next to `str` because it is part of a larger array of pointers or some `struct`.

If not a valid assumption, any value `i > 1` leads to *undefined behavior* (UB).  Using 1 is valid to find the address 1 past `str` and not certainly valid to de-reference.

> which one should be preferable for speed?

There are not functional equivalent so a speed comparison it moot.  Likely similar speeds.

Answer (score 2):

|Pointers and arrays are often confused as both are wrongly called "strings" or "C strings". A C string is an array of `char`s terminated by the ***null terminating character***. A pointer can only reference such an array, but it is not itself a "C string"

1. `char *str = "hello world"`

- `&str[i]` - has type `char *` and references `i`th element of the string literal `"hello world"
- `&str` has type `char **` (pointer to pointer to char) and (&str)[1] will reference next **pointer** to char located just past the the str itself

2. `char str[12] = "hello world"`

- `&str[i]` - has type `char *` and references `i`th element of the array str
- `&str` has type `char (*)[12]` (pointer to an array of 12 `char`s) and `(&str)[1]` will reference the next **array** of 12 `char` elements

Answer (score 1):

A "string" in C is an array of characters (`char`), followed by a 0 at the end. The `const char*` points to the first character.

```
const char* string = "hello world";
printf("%s\n", string);  // prints "hello world"
```

`string[i]` is the i-th char in `string`. And `&string[i]` is its address.
(So `&string[0]` is the same as `string` itself).
Because the characters in the string come one after the other, their addresses are also sequential, so `&string[i]` is the same as `string + i`.

Because in C a string goes from the start until the 0 character, the pointer `&string[i]` is effectively a string starting at the i'th character, until the end of the original string.

```
const char* string = "hello world";
printf("%s\n", &string[6]);  // prints "world"
printf("%s\n", string + 6);  // prints "world"
```

---

This can be used to get a "substring" that has a different start, but the same end. To get a substring with a different end too, it would be needed to modify the original string to add a 0 character, or make a copy of it.

```
char string[] = "hello world"; // (non-const string on stack, for this example)
string[5] = '\0'; // replace ' ' by 0
printf("%s\n", string);  // prints "hello"
printf("%s\n", string + 2);  // prints "llo"
```

---

For the operator precedence:

An expression `pointer[i]` is always equivalent to `*(pointer + i)`: It increments the pointer by i, and then dereferences it. So when it is a pointer to an array, it will get the i'th element.

`&string[i]` corresponds to `&(string[i])`: It gets the i'th character, and then again takes its address. (Which can be used as a string, as before.)

`(&string)[j]` is different: it first takes `&string`, the address of the pointer `string` itself (so a pointer to a pointer). Then increments that pointer by `j` units, and dereferences it.
This will fail, because the pointer `string` is not an element of an array, so there is no `(&string)[j]` for j>0.

Comment: Rather than use `string` in sample code for different types, consider using different names, perhaps `const char* pointer_to_string` and `char string_in_char_array[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Having `char *str;` as the pointer, `&str` is a `char **` pointer, so `(&str)[3]` will require `ptr` also to be a cell in an array, and `(&str)[3]` will represent the pointer that is three pointer positions further in memory.

On the other side, `&(str[3])` will address the pointer three positions after and will represent the address of the fourth character in the array.

The parenthesisless expression `&str[3]` is interpreted as `&(str[3])` (as a general rule, monadic right operators have higher precedence over left ones)